# where is AWS CLI installed during a Visual Studio Team Services build

Tags: python, pip, windows-server-2012-r2, aws-cli

'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Visual Studio Team Services 'Hosted' build

During a VSTS 'Hosted' build, Im running a windows batch file with the following:

```
    python -c "import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve('https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py', r'C:\python27\Tools\get-pip.py')"
    python C:\python27\Tools\get-pip.py
    python -m pip install --upgrade --user awscli
    aws s3 cp /source s3://bucketName
```

how do I find where aws cli is installed?

I looked in these locations:

C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI

C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon\AWSCLI

Comment: I have a similar problem but I install it from Python pip - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112463/can-aws-cli-be-installed-using-python2-7. Oops I see you install it from there too.

Comment: It might be installed at `c:\Python27\Scripts\aws.cmd`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112839/492336

Comment: check using  pip list

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about the `awscli` module, since you're installing the module in the user space it's most probably installed in `%APPDATA%\python\<python_version>\site-packages\awscli` - if you're unsure you can always do:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

To get the actual path of `site-packages`, then you can find your module path there.

However, if you're looking for the actual 'command line tools', the build script will save the `aws.cmd` script in `%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts` (you can get the base path with `python -m site --user-base` which will point to `%APPDATA%\Python` for common setups) so if you want to invoke `aws.cmd` do:

```
%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts\aws.cmd s3 cp /source s3://bucketName
```

P.S. Just noticed that this question was posted on March 15th and got resurrected by somebody. It's most likely that the OP has found his/her answer by now, but keeping the answer for posterity.

Comment: Yeah, I put the bounty because my own question was too new for a bounty yet. Anyway, I found the answer I needed later and posted it. I'll award the bounty anyway, thanks.

Comment: @sashoalm - ah, that explains a lot, I wasn't looking at the comments or the date :D I've had a similar conundrum a couple of weeks back so the research I took to get to the bottom of it was still fresh.