# Can AWS CLI be installed using Python2.7?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

I installed AWS CLI from Python 2.7 using `python -m pip install awscli`. It seemed to install, but then when trying to run `aws`, I get `'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

The [documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-path) that I should add to PATH this:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

But this is for Python3. Where is it installed for Python2? There is nothing in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\` (I checked). And does installation work for Python2 or only for Python3?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching, the file was located at `c:\Python27\Scripts\aws.cmd`. But it was `aws.cmd`, not `aws.exe`. So to make `aws` work, you need to add it to the PATH:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Python27\Scripts
```

After that it works:

```
c:\Python27>aws --version
File association not found for extension .py
aws-cli/1.11.148 Python/2.7.14rc1 Windows/10 botocore/1.7.6
```

Although there is still this weird `File association not found for extension .py` error.

**Edit:** From @zwer's comment about "File association not found for extension .py", you need to execute this from an administrator cmd prompt:

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File=c:\Python27\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Comment: Since you've resolved the path issue, when it comes to the error itself, standard Python installation associates .py files with the `python.exe` binary (so, essentially, does what **shebang** defines on POSIX systems, but system-wide). It's a bad assumption on awscli's side that you did associate .py files, but you can easily fix that by first defining the file type with: `assoc .py=Python.File` and then setting up your Python interpreter for it: `ftype Python.File=c:\Python27\python.exe "%1" %*` (given your path above, that should be the path to Python binary, adjust if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to get this done is

1. Install pip
2. pip Install awscli
3. aws configure
4. keys and identification keys access parameters

To Install PIP: 
need to update YUM Release version and then install python-pip

```
#yum install epel-release    
#yum install python-pip
```

Install AWSCLI:

```
#pip install awscli
```

Configure AWSCLI:

```
#aws configure
aws_access_key_id=<########>
aws_secret_access_key=<####################>
Default Region[None]: region=us-west-2
format[none]: json
```

you can find these configuration parameters later in file::

```
~/.ssh/aws/credentials
```